# How can I improve my listening for a selection of Chinese HSK6 words?

Tags: learning-methods, chinese, listening

I downloaded [Mandarin Corner](https://mandarincorner.org/)'s mp3s where, for each of the 2500 Chinese HSK6 words, Teacher Eileen says the word twice, then its example sentence twice.  I note down the words which I don't near-instantaneously recognize through listening.  The list currently looks like this (100 words per mp3; 25 mp3s total; these are the first 4 mp3s):

> 1: 案例 安置 疤 巴结 拜访 败坏 颁布 斑纹 抱负 曝光 暴露 包围 保卫 备份 被告 奔波 本事 (17)
> 2: 碧玉 鞭策 辩护 便于 辩证 编织 标记 飙升 标题 表彰 别致 不禁 补救 布局 补贴 部位 布置 捕捉 裁缝 才干 财务 财政 残留 (23)
> 3: 仓促 仓库 操劳 操练 嘈杂 策划 层次 查获 诧异 搀 产业 偿还 猖狂 昌盛 畅通 常务 倡议 沉着 秤 承包 乘务员 成效 诚心 诚挚 池塘 赤字 充当 冲击 崇敬 冲突 (30)
> 4: 重阳节 抽空 稠密 处境 出路 出身 出息 出洋相 喘气 垂直 伺候 摧残 搭档 答复 大伙 打击 打猎 大体 打仗 代价 当前 当事人 (21)

With almost no exceptions, I can read these words with little effort.  My problem is that, when listening, I need time to think, but neither real-world materials nor the HSK6 exam give you time to think (native-Chinese speaking speed can reach 250 characters per minute [[ref.](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/ldc/llog/icslp06_final.pdf)], so you may only get half a second to recognize a word).

I'm just wondering what I can actually do with this list of words to improve.  It looks like there'll be maybe 600 or 700 when I've finished all 25 mp3s.

**Question**: How can I improve my listening for a selection of Chinese HSK6 words?

Comment: Are you reading them without effort because you are understanding the meaning of the characters? What if you read it with a phonetic version (e.g. pinyin); can you still understand it without effort?